# How to sort vim folds alphabetically

Tags: sorting, vim

My `.vimrc` is organized into multiple sections and subsections, each associated with a **foldmarker.**

[image: vim foldmarkers]

How can I easily sort the folds alphabetically by their description, retaining the rest of the fold block as it is?
There is no requirement to do the sorting in vim itself, as long as the process is not manual.

I.e. the following section:

```
" Syntastic --------------------------------------------------{{{3

foo bar baz

" Emmet.vim --------------------------------------------------{{{3

let g:user_emmet_mode='n'
let g:user_emmet_leader_key='<leader>e'
```

should look like this after sorting:

```
" Emmet.vim --------------------------------------------------{{{3

let g:user_emmet_mode='n'
let g:user_emmet_leader_key='<leader>e'

" Syntastic --------------------------------------------------{{{3

foo bar baz
```

There is an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554191/sorting-vim-folds), which concerns itself with a similar problem, the solutions offered were not of much help for my particular issue.

Comment: Well, actually, I would answer exactly like they answer in that question. Maybe tell more how your question is different from that one

Comment: How is the foldtext generated?

Comment: The solutions to the older question use vim macros. These seem to not work for nested folds. I should have made that clearer. 
It is only required to sort level two folds alphabetically. All other folds should remain untouched.

Comment: For my usecase it would be best, if the highest level folds in a visual selection would be sorted. I.e. some non-recursive method.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt the foldtext is created manually

Comment: @jottr maybe you could edit your question and mention the nested folding constraint(s)?